# Why does Visual Studio undo pending changes while saving EDMX update?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Posting this Q&A in the hope it helps others avoid a time-waste.

I've updated my .EDMX many times before, but today noticed this issue.  And - I assume related - the updated .EDMX has missing mappings.

**Question**

Why is Visual Studio partially undoing the changes?

**Steps**

I update my .EDMX from the database using the usual dialog

[image: update from database]

That closes as normal.  But after I press Save, I see this:

[image: undoing pending changes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot solved this.  Restarting Visual Studio wasn't enough.